# Como puedo poner una llave foránea a dos tablas o como puedo hacer un campo que me tome en cuenta datos creados de dos diferentes tablas

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

Perdón si el titulo es algo confuso, anexo ayuda el modelo de una base de datos para un hospital
[image: No estoy muy seguro de si esta bien formada la base de datos asi que si me quieren dar recomendaciones les agradezco]

Mi objetivo es que en la tabla cita_medica pueda asignarle una cita a los beneficiarios y a los afiliados ya que a los dos se les puede asignar cita pero no tengo idea de como hacerle y no encontre documentación

Comment: Podrías crear una tabla que sirva como intermediaria, en ella solo agregarías las llaves foraneas de las tablas que quieres relacionar

Comment: pero como hago en caso de querer asignarle una cita a un afiliado? ya que estarian sus datos en la tabla de afiliados pero el beneficiario que pondria xd?

Comment: Detalla el escenario, entre más detalles, mejor análisis. Por cierto, lectura recomendada: https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4433/822

Comment: Basicamente es la respuesta que te dieron... porque tenes 2 tablas que guardan basicamente pacientes? ser beneficiario o afiliado es basicamente una caracteristica del paciente...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bueno lo que yo haría sería juntar las dos tablas ya que tienen datos similares y agregaría un campo el cual sería algo como tipo de paciente y quedaría de la esta forma

```
Tabla paciente
Id_paciente
Cedula_paciente
Contraseña_paciente
Nombre_paciente
Celular_paciente
Correo_paciente
Tipo_paciente
Rol_idrol
```

```
Tabla_tipo_paciente
Id_tipo_paciente
Tipo_paciente
```

Comment: Considero que dada la longitud de ambas, tus 2 respuestas pueden quedar en una sola ;)

Comment: No agregues otra respuesta.. usa el boton [edit] y agrega todo en una... de paso, mira el [tour]